# java Import comes grey whenn semicolon

Tags: java

Hi there i basically have a problem with one of my codes.

when i add import code with the semicolon ; , it becomes grey and when i remove it it becomes green but i know it wont execute as it ask for a semicolon but still fails to compile.

`import org.timesheet.Web.helpers.EntityGenerator`

how do i fix this problem i am a newbie to java as well, so would need step by step guide to how to fix it

i also keep getting this error message when i compile it.

`Information:Using javac 1.7.0_67 to compile java sources Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'org.timesheet'
Information:06/02/2015 12:50 - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 1 sec
C:\Users\nazia.kausar\Documents\ACP\acp_repos\TimeSheet\src\main\java\org\timesheet\Web\helpers\WelcomeController.java
Error:(8, 33) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EntityGenerator
  location: package org.timesheet.Web.helpers
Error:(18, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EntityGenerator
  location: class org.timesheet.Web.helpers.WelcomeController
C:\Users\nazia.kausar\Documents\ACP\acp_repos\TimeSheet\src\main\java\org\timesheet\impl\HibernateDao.java
Information:java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Information:java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`

Comment: That's probably an IDE error. Try rebooting it

Comment: Listen to the compiler. It knows how it likes its code.

Comment: Which IDE? IIRC IntelliJ IDEA marks imports light grey if they're not used in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a semicolon in the `import` statement:

```
import org.timesheet.Web.helpers.EntityGenerator;
```

However, if the line is grayed-out and your compiler issues an error, it is very likely that either your import is faulty (e.g. typo) or the file cannot be found. You should check your dependency then.

Comment: would it be anything to do with the pom file like can i add a profile on pom to let the import work?

Comment: Either ``org.timesheet.*`` is one of your own packages, then make sure that this dependency exists, or it is a third party library that you have to include in your project. If you are working with Maven, then ``pom.xml`` is the right place to start. Check whether the project that provides your ``EntityGenerator`` is present there.

Comment: I suppose, you are following [this tutorial](https://vrtoonjava.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/part-4-adding-spring-mvc-part-1/)? Then ``EntityGenerator`` is a class you have to create yourself in ``org.timesheet.web.helpers`` first. Also notive that ``Web`` is written with a lower-case letter in the tutorial, while you are importing it with a capital letter ``W``.

Comment: yes thats the one i tried to correct it but its not letting me on intelli j it keeps combing the folders ex: web.helpers

Comment: You have to create your folder structure accordingly, i.e. create ``org/timesheet/web/helpers/`` within your project (in your ``src/main/java`` path, if you have a Maven project). Then put your ``EntityGenerator`` file there.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help! figured out it was the capitals! i had to rename all my files

Answer (score 0):

Imports should end with `;`.

The fact that it becomes 'gray' is kind of IDE dependent, but it is most likely that it is suggestion that you are not using this import.

Make sure the import is correct.

If you are using eclipse/intelliJ delete the import. Move cursor to first usage use `quick fix` shortcut (which is `Ctrl + 1` for eclipse and `alt + enter` for IntelliJ) which will suggest you import and add it automatically on top of file.

[image]